# How to restart a systemd service whenever Chromium-browser opens/launches?

Tags: linux, systemd, services, chrome, daemon

I have a systemd service that must be restarted whenever Chromium-browser opens/launches.

```
[Unit]
Description=Load cgroup configs
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStartPre=/bin/echo "Processing /etc/cgconfig.conf ..."
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/cgconfigparser -l /etc/cgconfig.conf
ExecStartPre=/bin/echo "Processing /etc/cgrules.conf ..."
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/cgrulesengd --logfile=/var/log/cgrulesengd.log
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This service is used to process the configuration files that are used to limit the CPU and Memory usage of Chromium-browser using CGroups.

This service is activated on the boot and then when I open the chromium browser and run the following commands, it return nothing.

```
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/browsers/tasks
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/browsers/tasks
```

BUT then I have to restart the service manually `service <service_name> restart`. After that, above commands return the PIDs used by the Chromium browser. For example

```
5314
5347
5349
5403
5603
```

How can I automate this service to restart automatically whenever there is a chromium launch? and I don't have to restart the service manually again and again.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the rules correctly, you should be able to do this without having to restart this service.

Some of these resources maybe helpful:

- [Cgroups from Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cgroups)
- [cgrules.service sample](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/cgrules.service?h=libcgroup)
- [cgconfig.service sample](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/cgconfig.service?h=libcgroup)
- [Starting a process in a control group](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/resource_management_guide/starting_a_process)

Comment: Please explain how the asker should go about setting the rules correctly; answers should be self-contained, without requiring the readers to follow links. (Links are still useful to provide more information or references, but they shouldn’t be necessary to use the answer.)

Comment: These are the basics things which everyone will try to search before asking any question here. Should not count as an answer. -1